# Can you access a variable using a pointer to avoid direct editing of a variable?

Tags: c++, memory

I was wondering if you could avoid secure variables in classes by assigning a pointer to a variable and then modifying the pointer to then modify the variable that is protected. This is entirely just a thought, but I've been learning about pointers recently and I dont know enough figure it out.

Comment: Can you give an example of that?

Comment: What do you mean by a "secure variable"? What is the real problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: If you're talking about `protected` and `private` member variables of C++ classes, then Yes, you can step on them with a rogue pointer. Which is to say that there is no security that prevents you from overwriting member variables. Needless to say (but I'm going to say it anyways), you should never do that.

Comment: User3386109 hit the question on the head, sorry for my bad vocab... the words just weren't coming to me.

Comment: Do you want the answer in C or C++?

Comment: You can do all sorts of things you shouldn't do if you try hard enough. Take a pointer to the beginning of the object. Increment that pointer to the right place and Shazam! You have the `private` variable you aren't supposed to get access to. Doing this requires you to abuse Undefined Behaviour though, so how long that exploit will do what you want it to do is anybody's guess.

Comment: Access protection applies to names, not data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't really understand what you thought, but I think you mention to `private` or `protected` variable and using pointers to change their values. If your question is same that, then my answer is "If you really want to change private variables then you can use a pointer. To avoid that, there is no other way than to use the pointer carefully". Below is a program to show changing `private variables` by using pointer.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
class Demo
{
private:
   int private_var_1;
   int private_var_2;
public:
   Demo()
   {
     private_var_1 = 1;
     private_var_2 = 2;
   }
   void show()
   {
        cout<<private_var_1<<" "<<private_var_2<<" ";
   }
}; 
int main() {
    Demo d;
    //now d.private_var_1 = 1 and d.private_var_2 = 2
    //BUT we can completely modify d.private_var_1 and d.private_var_2
    int* pointer = (int*)&d;
    *pointer = 111111;  //then d.private_var_1 = 111111 
    pointer += 1;       //move the pointer to next 4 bytes, now
                        //the pointer point to d.private_var_2
    *pointer = 222222;  //then d.private_var_2 = 222222;
    d.show();
    return 0;
}
```